# Mvc 4 single page application view navigation to different sections of site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I'm embarking in my first spa mvc 4 app and I've watched the Steve Sanderson talk which was great but his final delivery tracker app ends up with 3 views that are all declared in the same view page. This is fine for a small app but how do you manage this on a larger scale when you have different sections of the site that have different data. The site I want to build needs to remain on a single page because I want to keep a chat window open similar to the Facebook style chat and i am going to be using SignalR to push data to the client in fixed sections within the app. Do I just use the @Ajax.actions to load up completely different sections of my site much as I would if I was just creating a non spa site? The plan is to keep the user in a specific section of the I site for a majority of the time, but I will want settings pages and user profile management pages that are defined in separate views.

Any good sample code would be greatly appreciated I'm planning to just use the bog standard spa with knockout and nav.js unless someone can suggest a more mature spa technology for mvc/entity framework that's got some good documentation and is popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is poor mans SPA, which is basically make my site like a standard ASP.NET MVC app so I have multiple views, multiple controllers and actions and I have a shell page with a container `div` which I use as the container for the whole site to load my views into with Ajax calls, so I have lots and lots of jQuery ajax calls, I've somewhat tried to refactor my client side JS and make a generic navigate to Javascript method (among other things) in my shell page, which I then invoke from the child views, so a click on a certain `ActionLink` in a particular child view and I would call my generic JS page loader: 
`GoToPage(controller, action, query)`
which will use jQuery Ajax to lad the destination controller/action/view into the container div in `shell.cshtml`. For navigation I use Ben Alman's [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) to detect hash change events and load the appropriate views into my container div. There are obvious downsides to this approach as you're rally not building a *real* SPA, you're making a server side app with a SPA facade, and actually the performance difference between this and a proper spa which only gets data from the server (not HTML) is slightly noticeable, however if you're a traditional ASP.NET MVC developer this saves you from having to take up new libraries like `Sammy.js` and knockout etc. The biggest downside of this is that you'll be writing a lot of repetitive wiring javascript which can quickly become a tangled mess, especially if you have a lot of forms. Though you can take certain steps to re-factor and reuse common code. So in summary generating views server side and retrieving them with Ajax probably isn't the most optimal SPA solution, but for me it had the least learning curve (none actually lol). I've recently been looking at [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/) and I think it finally provides a very viable solution to creating SPAs, I specially like how unlike `Sammy.js` you don't have to load all views on the initial page load, even if the user isn't going to visit those pages. A nice getting started tutorial is provided [here](http://stephenwalther.com/?p=699).

Comment: thanks for your feedback, your "poor mans approach" is actually something I've considered. In relation to not making any server side calls, I don't see how SPA can be the answer to desktop application on the web if you have to load all the data and logic in one view, I'm going to check out your links to durandal as it sounds like this might be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @Rob I also forgot to mention there is a course on SPAs (with Durandal) on [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/single-page-apps-jumpstart), it's a paid subscription but has a 200 minutes free trial as well.